# Deny Access to Folder

Tags: permissions

I am running 20.04 LTS.  I am trying to deny a user access to a folder.  In the terminal the user doesn't have permission, but in the GUI it prompts for admin credentials.  Is there a way to stop it from prompting for credentials, the GVFSD-Admin, and just deny them permission?

Comment: It's a "convenience". On the command line, a failing `cat /etc/shadow` would be followed by `sudo !!`. Nautilus ("the GUI") does this automatically. As long as the `$USER` isn't in the `sudo` group, access will be denied.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent a user with Sudo from being prompted for a password to the folder?

Comment: Probably not, but this is a second Qusetion asked as a Comment. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].